# How to fine-tune a pre-trained model for customer service like tasks chatbot?

Tags: natural-language-processing, chat-bots, fine-tuning

I want to make a trainable conversational bot that can respond to customer service questions. The bot should be able to adapt to different domains based on the dataset provided by the user (a company data science engineer).

I have a general idea of how to approach this problem, but I need some guidance and feedback. My plan is to start from a pre-trained model like Flan T5, GPT, etc. Then, I would do an intermediate fine-tuning on a general conversational dataset like PersonaChat or DailyDialog. Finally, I would do a final fine-tuning on the customer service conversation dataset from the user.

Is this a reasonable approach? What are some potential challenges or pitfalls that I should be aware of? What are some best practices or resources for fine-tuning conversational models? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your approach to building a trainable conversational bot sounds reasonable. Starting with a pre-trained model and then fine-tuning it on conversational datasets is a common and effective approach. Remember that building an effective conversational bot is an iterative process. Continuous monitoring, evaluation, and improvement based on user feedback are key to refining the performance and usability of your bot.